# Pygame - walking a sprite diagonally

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am new to python and I am working through the "Adventures in Python" book by Craig Richardson.

Here is my code and my challenge is to get a sprite to walk diagonally when two keys are pressed.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

def move(image1, image2):
    global count
    if count < 5:
        image = image1
    elif count >= 5:
        image = image2

    if count >= 10:
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
    return image

windowSize = [400, 300]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(windowSize)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

standing = pygame.image.load('standing.png')

down1 = pygame.image.load('down1.png')
down2 = pygame.image.load('down2.png')

up1 = pygame.image.load('up1.png')
up2 = pygame.image.load('up2.png')

left1 = pygame.image.load('side1.png')
left2 = pygame.image.load('side2.png')

right1 = pygame.transform.flip(left1, True, False)
right2 = pygame.transform.flip(left2, True, False)

white = pygame.color.Color("#FFFFFF")

count = 0
x = 0
y = 0

done = False
while not done:
    screen.fill(white)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    #player movement
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        image = move(right1, right2)
        x += 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        image = move(down1, down2)
        y += 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
        image = move(up1, up2)
        y -= 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        image = move(left1, left2)
        x -= 1
    else:
        image = standing


    screen.blit(image, (x, y))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(32)

pygame.quit()
```

My question is in regard to the #player movement section. If I use elif, my sprite cannot move diagonally. If I use ifs, the sprite only "walks" for the last if (ie. in this case, to the left when 'a' is pressed). When s, w, or d is pressed, the standing image is used and the sprite slides around. How do I fix this?

```
    #player movement
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        image = move(right1, right2)
        x += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        image = move(down1, down2)
        y += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        image = move(up1, up2)
        y -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:    # only this if/else seems to work.
        image = move(left1, left2)
        x -= 1
    else:
        image = standing
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure the if-elif clauses differently. Separate the horizontal from the vertical movement. Check if the player is moving left or right with an if-elif block and if yes, move the player horizontally, then do the same for the y-axis.

```
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    image = move(right1, right2)
    x += 1
elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
    image = move(left1, left2)
    x -= 1

if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    image = move(down1, down2)
    y += 1
elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
    image = move(up1, up2)
    y -= 1

# Set the `image` to `standing` if none of the keys is pressed.
if not any((keys[pygame.K_d], keys[pygame.K_a], keys[pygame.K_w], keys[pygame.K_s])):
    image = standing
```

Comment: Okay. I understand. This way, two ifs are activated when two keys are pressed. To add to this, why would the else clause not work? Because my next challenge is to figure out how to keep the sprite in the same direction it moved, instead of standing when no keys are pressed. I will figure this out by myself before posting.

Comment: Just add an else clause at the bottom (in place of the `if not any(...`) and see what happens. It will always change the image to `standing` if neither `s` nor `w` are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be something to do with your if statements. If you use all ifs, once you press a key, it would keep executing that until it is released. Try something like this:

```
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    image = move(right1, right2)
    x += 1
elif keys[pygame.K_a]:  
    image = move(left1, left2)
    x -= 1
if keys[pygame.K_s]:
    image = move(down1, down2)
    y += 1
elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
    image = move(up1, up2)
    y -= 1
```

Hope this helps!